# Is "Checkers" on topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Would anyone be interested in expanding the scope of this site to include "Checkers" by creating a "checkers-tag" for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say no. Our sister site [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/) already has a [[checkers]](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/checkers) tag. While some overlap between Stack Exchange sites isn't a bad thing per sé, we should not deliberately create it without any supporting arguments.